# Angular scope issues with $controller inheritance

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 controllers `MainCtrl` and `IndexCtrl`.

I can't access from my `IndexCtrl` to value that was assigned in function. Did someone have same problem?

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $location){
   $scope.test = 'test';

   function onComplete(user) {
      $scope.user = user;
      $location.path('/secondDirection');//IndexCtrl is acting here 
   }
}

function IndexCtr($scope, $controller) {
   $controller('MainCtrl', {$scope:$scope}  //I inherit my MainCtrl scope
   $scope.test //test;
   $scope.user //undefined
}
```

Comment: user has defined inside your MainCtrl function. So if you want to use user you need to call onComplete function or otherwise put it outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

try to angular.extend the sub controller

```
function IndexCtr($scope, $controller){
   angular.extend(this,$controller('MainCtrl', {$scope:$scope}))  //I inherit my 
   $scope.test //test;
   $scope.user //undefined
}
```

Comment: a controller is a nothing more than a constructor function

Comment: It doesn't work. I use it to reduce other controllers, I can declare suitable methods in MainCtrl  such as debounce, animate, publish, subscribe, throttle, others...